# Parse HTML string into DOM using JavaScript, but ignore broken tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML string:

```
"<div> one is<than three </div>"
```

is there an elegant way to parse this string to HTML using JavaScript? Every solution tends to create `<than` tag. Can anyone advise me on this issue, or should I change the solution to avoid this?

(Even StackOverflow has an issue if I put `<than` as a plain text)

Comment: what do you mean by parse?

Comment: Create a valid DOM structure from it.

Comment: show how the output should be

Comment: <div>
  one is<then three
</div>, but as html object.

Comment: Are you trying to insert that string into the DOM?

Comment: @DizzyBlack, as that's invalid HTML it's going to be parsed in a specific way. The actual issue is that the contents contains an unescaped `<` character. Rather than trying to build a custom language or parser, it would be safer to fix the actual issue, which appears to be the content.

Comment: Attempting to parse invalid mark-up == whole can of worms.

Comment: Yes. Cant find a way to keep actual tags, but escape "one is&#ltthen three".

Comment: @zzzzBov I wanted to create a simple text editor and enable basic tags, but I have a problem validating the input. Probably, I'll have to use/create more advanced one in this case..

Comment: @DizzyBlack, so rather than succumbing to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), ask about the *actual* problem you're having, rather than your perceived solution to said problem.

Comment: @zzzzBov True, I'm in a little time hurry here, so fell into the temptation to find the quickest and simpliest solution.. At least I think now that the solution I want is not possible/good. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As `<` shouldn't be part of valid HTML document, you should consider using `&lt;` character.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: I thought there is a simple way to tell, if "<" is a part of a valid tag and escape it if not.